# output of the system call in printf behaves strangely

Tags: c

If you run the below program, you will see the same IP address output. It suppose to give distinct IP. (Tried in Linux with gcc compiler)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    struct in_addr ip_1, ip_2;

    ip_1.s_addr = 0x300a620a;
    ip_2.s_addr = 0x117630a;

    printf("ip_1 = %s \t ip_2 = %s\n",inet_ntoa(ip_1), inet_ntoa(ip_2));
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this `printf`?  But if we have two `printf` like below, the answer is correct.

```
printf("ip_1 = %s\n",inet_ntoa(ip_1));
printf("ip_2 = %s\n",inet_ntoa(ip_2));
```

Answer (score 11):

Reading the documentation for `inet_ntoa` we find:

> The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

You make two calls to `inet_ntoa` and the second call overwrites the string that the first call returned.

Additionally, it is unspecified in which order the arguments to the function call to `printf` (or any other function for that matter) will be evaluated, so you can't really know which of the calls to `inet_ntoa` will be first and which will be second.

`inet_ntoa` is an old function and shouldn't be used in new code. It doesn't understand other address families than IP4, it's not thread safe, it uses a static buffer that gives this kind of unexpected behaviors. Check if your standard library has `getnameinfo` and use that instead, it is a bit harder to use but it will be much more correct now and definitely in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Got clarified. Yes it is due to static allocated buffer. I can reproduce this behaviour by the following code. The second one overwrites the first one. char* fun(char *str)
{
    static char a[10];
    strcpy(a,str);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    char *ptr1, *ptr2;
    ptr1 = fun("hello");
    ptr2 = fun("world");
    printf("ptr1 = %s\n",ptr1);
    printf("ptr2 = %s\n",ptr2);
    return 0;
}

Comment: @GnanaGuruNatarajan Btw. It is unspecified which of the two function calls will be first. I'll edit my answer with a few more details.